# Image information in database for android

Tags: android, database, image, listview, checkbox

Let say i have listview with images and checkbox. You can make the picture favorite by clicking checkbox. Let say i have a button "show my fav pics", which loads information from database and opens listview with my favorite images.

My question is, when user checks the checkbox what should i store in the database against my favorite picture. R.drawable.pic1 will not work for sure, because of random generation of ID.

Help F1,F1

Comment: R.drawable.pic1 should be fixed through the lifetime of application, these are generated at compile-time not run-time. You should be able to use those.

Comment: @Gaurav Arora... are you sure that once the id for pic is generated then it will be permanent until the app is not uninstalled?

Comment: The Resource ID integers are created at compile time. Therefore constant in your app once built. So, they'd be constants for an APK.